# Change the entry point in Asp.Net Core's React + Redux starter template to a controller

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-core, .net-core, create-react-app

I have successfully installed and run the React + Redux starter template that is provided with .Net Core 2.1 (I'm talking about the project created with`dotnet new reactredux`).

Now I would like to change my entry point from `index.html` to my own controller inside the Asp.Net.Core project.

Since the `create-react-app` is configured to use `index.html` as an entry point, I've had to:

1. Delete the `index.html` file
2. "Eject" the dependencies (`npm run eject`) in order to modify the configuration file for webpack (I removed the `InterpolateHtmlPlugin` and `HtmlWebpackPlugin` plugins from webpack config, as well as all references to `index.html` in `build.js` and `start.js`
3. Add a `HomeController.cs` to the project:

---

```
namespace ReactReduxSpa.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
```

---

4. Add the corresponding `Index.cshtml` file to my project with pretty much the same content as the former `index.html` file, except that I now manual insert the generated script bundle:

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000">
    <base href="~/" />
    <link rel="manifest" href="~/manifest.json">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="~/favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="~/static/js/bundle.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

5. In `Startup.cs` I changed `app.UseMvc(…)` to:

---

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        template: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

    routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
        name: "spa-fallback",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
});
```

---

My home controller is now executed when accessing the site and the site itself works as intended. However, I'm getting thousands of errors in the console for these requests:

[image: Requests to sockjs-node]
[image: Errors in the console]

Looking at the response, I see that the server simply served the content of my `Index.cshtml` view instead of letting these requests through. I assume these are used for development to sync the site and the sources.

To sum it up: I don't think that I'm doing it the right way, but I don't know how to do it differently. My goal is simply to replace the static `index.htm` with some dynamic content (some bits need to be generated on server side).

Comment: Can you add the code of your HomeController.cs, as well as some example errors from the console?

Comment: @DanielBeckmann : done. Not sure this will help much tough. The errors are caused by the content of /sockjs-node/ requests being incorrect as I said.

Comment: The starter templates are designed with separated backend and frontend in mind. So I think it would be better to don't use the starter templates and use sth. like https://reactjs.net/, because bending the behavior could be really tricky, as you already encountered.